# Cognos 8 Sort Order by Column

Tags: cognos, cognos-8, cognos-bi

I'm working in Cognos 8, and I have the first three fields in a report:
Agency
Org
Name

I'm displaying Agency and Name always... Org is displayed based on a Render Variable. So on the prompt page, if the user selects yes, display Org, it's displayed on the report. If they select no, it's not displayed.

The sort order needs to be Agency, Org, Name.... however, if Org does not show, I need the sort order to be Agency, Name.

However, even when the Org is not rendered, it's not sorting Agency, Name. it's still sorting with Org in there.

How can I force it to not sort by Org if Org isn't rendered?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Personally when using render variable, I prefer to use blocks.
So, in your case it means you should create two blocks and then put a list in each block. 
The data source of the list can be identical, but the sorting is different:

[image: Two Lists inside separated blocks]